# Best way to save extracted features for future training deep learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using the VGG19 architecture to extract features from my images. Here is my code to do so:

```
model = VGG19(include_top=False)
image_paths = glob.glob('train/*/*')

def extract_features(model, path):
  img_path = path
  img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224,224))
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
  x = preprocess_input(x)
  features = model.predict(x)

for path in image_paths:
  extract_features(model, path)
```

I want to save each feature in format where I can later use it for deep learning, in torch or tf. Normally, I would just append each `features` into a list and save that list as a csv, but I've run into issues feeding lists into deep learning models. How do I save this data in a proper format?

Comment: if they are numpy: np.save(...)? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html or why not a pickle?

Comment: np.save makes sense to save the final tensor, but to what data structure do I want to append each `features`?

Comment: Maybe you could save the model at checkpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

Save the features per file, e.g. for cat.png save it as cat.npy; and as you go over your list of files (cat.png, dog.png, snake.png), first check if the feature was already created and directly load the .npy file.

The second approach is using a dictionary data structure, where you use the index of the sample as the key, and the extracted feature as the value. Example:

```
index = 123
feature = extract_feature(...)
dictionary[index] = feature
```

You can save this dictionary to pickle. Then load it the next time, and directly pull the features for an index from the dictionary.